# Sinch Service not starting in Android

Tags: java, android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I was trying out the sample programs provided by `Sinch` and was getting a NullPointerException. I traced the code and found that it was caused by my device not connecting to the `Sinch`Service.

The code is as follows

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements SinchService.StartFailedListener {

    private Button mLoginButton;
    private EditText mLoginName;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        mLoginName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginName);

        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginClicked();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        mLoginButton.setEnabled(true);
        getSinchServiceInterface().setStartListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mSpinner != null) {
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailed(SinchError error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (mSpinner != null) {
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStarted() {
        openPlaceCallActivity();
    }

    private void loginClicked() {
        String userName = mLoginName.getText().toString();

        if (userName.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!getSinchServiceInterface().isStarted()) {
            getSinchServiceInterface().startClient(userName);
            showSpinner();
        } else {
            openPlaceCallActivity();
        }
    }

    private void openPlaceCallActivity() {
        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, PlaceCallActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainActivity);
    }

    private void showSpinner() {
        mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mSpinner.setTitle("Logging in");
        mSpinner.setMessage("Please wait...");
        mSpinner.show();
    }
}
```

I could see that since the service is not connecting I am not getting a correct output when I call `getSinchServiceInterface()`. It always returns null. My device is connected to the internet and the backend app in the `Sinch` dashboard seems to be working fine too.

LogCat:

```
 12-22 17:43:38.432 2301-2301/com.login_signup_screendesign_demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.login_signup_screendesign_demo, PID: 2301
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  at calling.LoginActivity.loginClicked(LoginActivity.java:78)
                                                                                  at calling.LoginActivity.access$000(LoginActivity.java:15)
                                                                                  at calling.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:32)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could be the cause of this error and how to solve it?

UPDATE:

I exactly copy pasted the android code downloaded from this [page](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/). I am using sinch-rtc-sample-calling app from that file. I compiled and ran the app separately and it was working fine. Then I copy pasted all the java and xml from that app into the one which I am working and it is not working. Why is this happening. This might be the reason for the NullPointerException. After copy pasting I found that the login button is disabled. That means the `onServiceConnected()` is not executing. I tried calling it manually and that is resulting in the NPE, but that is happening correctly in the standalone app. I am getting these kind of problems only upon integration.

PS : I updated the manifest and gradle as per the new files.

Comment: It's most likely that you have a problem with you import

Comment: Make sure the Sinch SDK is inported and linked correct. Follow the steps on Sinch.com/docs/voice/android

Comment: @cjensen You can find my complete project [here](https://github.com/RajNirmal/iListen). Please tell me if there is anything wrong in the placement of the libs folder or the gradle dependency.

Comment: @Tyson : have u resolved the exception??

Comment: @Androidjack-RajeshGosemath No. I have not yet resolved it. I tried to write my own interface and managed to get the app up and running but if you could solve the error then it would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Have had the same issue over the past few days.

In my case it is because I hadn`t added the following in the manifest under application node

```
<service android:name=".SinchService"/>
```

Make sure that the setting is in your application manifest. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

everything looks fine, uncomment the commented part because there is one condition which is being checked and it returns

`private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
}`

before getting SinchService and Also check your

```
private static final String APP_KEY = "app_key";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "app_secret";
private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
```

in `SinchService.java`, are the correct or not.

Comment: I have changed the App_key and App_Secret keys as per my account

Comment: uncomment the commented part. I have tried this and it works fine or post you logcat

Comment: I tried with the commented part but getting the error. Please refer the logcat.

Comment: `at calling.LoginActivity.loginClicked(LoginActivity.java:78)` in my code it is `openPlaceCallActivity();` and remove `getSinchServiceInterface().startClient(userName);` which is before the `if (userName.isEmpty())` also you have comment `loginClicked();` and remove `checkForNull();` it is creating problem i think because my code is working fine after changing it as yours. And your code is working fine on my pc once againg check your App_key and App_Secret keys

Comment: I edited the code and still getting the error in `getSinchService`

Comment: I did have some trouble importing the jar files in my app. Could this be caused because of that..I imported only the .jar files. the other files like arm64 , X86 are not imported.. It kept throwing errors so I imported only `sinch-android-rtc-3.9.8`

Comment: may be your imports are not performed correctly, do one thing [download sinch](http://download.sinch.com/android/3.9.10/sinch-android-rtc-3.9.10.zip) and then [see this](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-app-to-app-voip-tutorial/#login). You have to follow these steps >> download the Sinch Android SDK then 
    1. Copy the entire libs folder to your project’s root directory
    2. Right-click the jar-files and choose “Add As Library”
    3. Create a new folder under src/main and name it jniLibs
    4. Move the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders into the newly created jniLibs folder